# Use array in PowerShell to delete folders?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, nuget, nuget-package

I am new to PowerShell and trying to get used to the strange syntax. I am trying to delete an array of folder paths. This is how I would do it in C#:

```
string[] folders = { '~/MyFolder/Test123', '~/MyFolder/Test987', '~/MyFolder/Test333' };
foreach (string item in folders) {
  $_.Remove()
}
```

How would I accomplish this in PowerShell? I found the below script, but I'm not sure how to change to use a pre-defined array. The included parameters actually come from NuGet:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$DTE.Solution.Projects|Select-Object -Expand ProjectItems|Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'Controllers'}|ForEach-Object{$_.Remove()}
```

How would I incorporate a string array to this instead of the hard coded "Controllers" name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to apply a string array to that filter:

```
$ProjectItems = 'Controllers','Robots','Weapons','Bacon'

$DTE.Solution.Projects|
Select-Object -Expand ProjectItems|
Where-Object{$ProjectItems -contains $_.Name}|
ForEach-Object{$_.Remove()}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it, but this one's pretty simple...

```
$folders = @("~/MyFolder/Test123", "~/MyFolder/Test987", "~/MyFolder/Test333")
$folders | Remove-Item
```